# detect keyboard search button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I change android soft keyboard to show search icon rather than Enter icon. My question is: how i can detect that user click on that search button?

Answer (score 48):

In the edittext you might have used your input method options to search.

```
<EditText
      android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
      android:inputType="text"/>
```

Now use the Editor listener on the EditText to handle the search event as shown below:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
           // Your piece of code on keyboard search click 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: my code doesn't run with this method!! it doesn't work for me

Comment: "it doesn't work" have never helped anyone. Being specific is the most awesome thing !

Comment: Note you seem to also need "android:inputType="text"" on modern (4+) android.

Comment: Great! Save lots of time. Was facing same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OnQuerySubmit` listener to get keyboard Search button click event.

Here's how,

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener
        = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        showLog("searchClickListener onQueryTextSubmit");
        getPhotos(searchView.getQuery().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        return false;
    }
};
```