# Android SearchView.OnQueryTextListener OnQueryTextSubmit not fired on empty query string

Tags: android, searchview

I am using **Android 4.1.2**. I have a `SearchView` widget on an `ActionBar`. Documentation on `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` from the android developer site states that `onQueryTextSubmit` is fired/Called when the user submits the query. This could be due to a keypress on the keyboard or due to pressing a submit button."

This does not happen if the search query is empty. I need this to fire on an empty query to clear the search filter of a ListView. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15):

It is not a bug, the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#SearchView.onSubmitQuery%28%29) deliberately checks against null and empty values:

```
private void onSubmitQuery() {
    CharSequence query = mQueryTextView.getText();
    if (query != null && TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(query) > 0) {
```

However you should be able to use the OnQueryTextChange callback to clear your ListView's filterables when the user clears the search EditText.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the research into the source code. I believe the OnQueryTextSubmit should be fired even if the query text is empty to allow us to clear the search filter and redisplay the whole unfiltered list. Even if I track the query text via the OnQueryTextChange event, the problem happens when the search text becomes empty. No event is fired. I would have to put another menu item on the Action bar just to redisplay the whole unfiltered list.

Comment: I suggest that when OnQueryTextChange informs you the search EditText is empty that you manually clear the filter yourself. I agree trying to call `onSubmitQuery()` with an empty string in any fashion just won't work.

Comment: In some cases you don't want to do immediate filtering (on text change), since the suggestions list is already doing that. So you filter the real list only on search click. And then it's necessary that the user has the possibility to clear this search. So yes, I also think that this check is a bug.

Comment: The reasoning: "it's in the source code, so it's not a bug" is completely flawed.

Answer (score 14):

I've an easier work around: use onQueryTextChange, but only render if it's empty.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    renderList(true);
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    if (searchView.getQuery().length() == 0) {
                            renderList(true);
                    }
                    return false;
            }
    });
```

Comment: why you don't use `newText` instead of `searchView.getQuery()`?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and end up with the following solution: custom `SearchView` + `OnQueryTextListener.onQueryTextChange`

Custom SearchView:

```
public class MySearchView extends SearchView {

private boolean expanded;

public MySearchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onActionViewExpanded() {
    super.onActionViewExpanded();
    expanded = true;
}

@Override
public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
    super.onActionViewCollapsed();
    expanded = false;
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}
}
```

Creating action and setting callback:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    searchAction = menu.add(0, SEARCH_ACTION_ID, 0 , getString(R.string.action_search));
    searchAction.setShowAsAction(SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);       
    searchView = new MySearchView(getSherlockActivity());
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchAction.setActionView(searchView);
}
```

And last the listener:

```
private OnQueryTextListener searchQueryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        search(query);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (searchView.isExpanded() && TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            search("");
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void search(String query) {
        // reset loader, swap cursor, etc.
    }

};
```

Tested on ABS 4.3.

Comment: It looks like you don't actually need a custom SearchView (with isExpanded()). isIconified() will do the same although you just take the inverse of that. As in if isIconified() is true and newText is empty, then the user just opened the SearchView, they didn't explicitly clear the text in the search view.

At least, that appears to work for ABS 4.x

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue with SearchView. My solution which consists of styling SearchView as shown in guide http://novoda.com/blog/styling-the-actionbar-searchview/ and setting OnEditorActionListener for EditText( [How do I trigger an action when the user has hit enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209404/how-do-i-trigger-an-action-when-the-user-has-hit-enter)) which is part of the SearchView was this:

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
searchPlate.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            //Do something
        }
        return false;

    }});
```

Comment: if you use v7 searchView, then searchPlace id is simply `R.id.search_src_text`, so `EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)`

Answer (score 5):

It's an old thread but I've found another solution (Kotlin code, but works in Java as well):

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            if(newText == null || newText.isEmpty())
                searchView.setQuery("\u00A0", false)
            return true
        }
```

`\u00A0` is a character that looks like space, but code-wise it is not. In other words SearchView is not empty. Empty string or `" "` would not work, because base SearchView uses trim, plus user may want to search text ending or beginning with space. But as far as I know users cannot enter `\u00A0` character.

Then all you need to do is override getQuery to `return super.getQuery.replace("\u00A0", "")` in your custom SearchView

Comment: Nice workaround! I modified it a little by using the zero-length space (\u200B) instead of the non-breaking space (\u00A0) so that a search view looks empty after the character is inserted.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a very dirty hack**, however it works correctly as expected, enabling the submit action even when there is no text entered (or entered then edited) in the SearchView.

It reflectively gains access to the inner TextView  editor action listener, wraps it in a custom listener where it delegates the call to the handler, and finally sets it as the action listener of the inner TextView.

```
    Class klass = searchView.getClass();
    try {
        Field currentListenerField = klass.getDeclaredField("mOnEditorActionListener");
        currentListenerField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView.OnEditorActionListener previousListener = (TextView.OnEditorActionListener) currentListenerField.get(searchView);
        TextView.OnEditorActionListener newListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (v.getText().length() == 0)
                    handleQuery("");
                return previousListener.onEditorAction(v, actionId, event);
            }
        };
        Field innerTextViewField = klass.getDeclaredField("mSearchSrcTextView");
        innerTextViewField.setAccessible(true);
        SearchView.SearchAutoComplete innerTextView = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) innerTextViewField.get(searchView);
        innerTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(newListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but can you explain the significance of the naming for "mOnEditorActionListener" and "mSearchSrcTextView" ? Can I name these anything I want? Also: I have a second SearchView on the same page that needs similar functionality. Do I need to name these differently when I add the listener to my second SearchView?

Comment: Why is a try/catch necessary for this solution, under what circumstances will it occur, and why do we throw the exception -- won't it simply crash?

Comment: Have a look at this link. Essentially we're modifying a field that was defined in Android SDK Library class (we don't have access to it through normal API). So this snippet will work for any `searchView` variable or other name, but changing `"mOnEditorActionListener"` will break it.

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java;l=1273?q=mOnEditorActionListener

Comment: The try/catch will only fail if there's a major redesign of `SearchView` class in a newer SDK version (the field is removed for example). So instead of a compilation error you'll get a runtime error. That's why I mentioned that it's a dirty hack :)

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned this behavior is intentional.  I gave up on a solution for `OnQueryChangeListener` and decided to workaround by implementing `OnEditorActionListener` on the SearchView's `EditText`, which you can get a handle to using `R.id.search_src_text`.  As long as you `setImeOptions` of the SearchView to `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH` you can handle a click on the keyboard search button.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9948214/1747491) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I can manage to do it simply by implementing the setOnQueryTextListener in this way:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchProductView).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                loadLocalData(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Where my loadLocalData method is

```
//query my DB
products = ProductDAO.findByIdList(idList);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
listView.setAdapter(<YOURADAPTER>)
```

This solution clears your query even if you clear the text with the "X" button

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, since empty query's are not supported I had to download and use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and then modify the onSubmitQuery() method.

This is how my onSubmitQuery() looks like now

```
private void onSubmitQuery() {
     CharSequence query = mQueryTextView.getText();
     if (query == null) {query = "";}
     if (mOnQueryChangeListener == null
             || !mOnQueryChangeListener.onQueryTextSubmit(query.toString())) {
         if (mSearchable != null) {
             launchQuerySearch(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN, null, query.toString());
             setImeVisibility(false);
         }
         dismissSuggestions();
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works... not nice to modify the library, but haven't found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example written in Kotlin:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

/**
 * Custom [SearchView] which can listen to empty submit events
 *
 * If the internal implementation would change, this will not crash at runtime. It will simply
 * ignore the empty submit listener and will continue to work as this is the base [SearchView]
 */
class EmptySubmitSearchView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : SearchView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private lateinit var searchAutoComplete: SearchAutoComplete

    private lateinit var internalEditorListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener

    private var emptySubmitListener: OnEmptySubmitListener? = null

    init {
        try {
            val defaultListenerField = SearchView::class.java
                .getDeclaredField("mOnEditorActionListener")
            defaultListenerField.isAccessible = true
            internalEditorListener = defaultListenerField.get(this) as TextView.OnEditorActionListener

            val searchAutoCompleteField = SearchView::class.java
                .getDeclaredField("mSearchSrcTextView")
            searchAutoCompleteField.isAccessible = true
            searchAutoComplete = searchAutoCompleteField.get(this) as SearchAutoComplete

            searchAutoComplete.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE && TextUtils.isEmpty(searchAutoComplete.text)) {
                    emptySubmitListener?.onEmptyTextSubmit()
                } else {
                    internalEditorListener.onEditorAction(v, actionId, event)
                }
                true
            }
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            //Some internal field has changed. Check there is a field called
            //mSearchSrcTextView and mOnEditorActionListener and if not update them accordingly
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set custom empty listener or null to remove it
     */
    fun setOnEmptySubmitListener(listener: OnEmptySubmitListener?) {
        emptySubmitListener = listener
    }

    interface OnEmptySubmitListener {
        fun onEmptyTextSubmit()
    }
}
```

You can set a custom listener with `setOnEmptySubmitListener` which will enable you to distinguish between events.

You can customize the actionId to respond to, in this case I had in my XML the EmptySubmitSearchView with this `android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite this behavior.
A workaround could be to clear the filter, when a user exits the searchview.

You could use the [OnCloseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327826/searchviews-oncloselistener-doesnt-work) for this. 
However, this can cause problems as well, depending on the minimum API Level you are developing for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to trigger the onQueryTextChange method manually through a TextWatcher:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, TextWatcher {

    // Basic onCreate(Bundle) here

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        final SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        final int resource_edit_text = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(resource_edit_text)).addTextChangedListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // Implementation of TextWatcher, used to have a proper onQueryTextChange (it doesn't update when the last character is removed)
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (final CharSequence charSequence, final int start, final int count, final int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (final CharSequence charSequence, final int start, final int before, final int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (final Editable editable) {
        if (editable.length() == 0)
            onQueryTextChange(editable.toString());
    }

    // Implementation of OnQueryTextChangeListener

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange (final String query) {
        // do stuff
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (final String query) {
        // do stuff
        return false;
    }
}
```

This all goes with all the default xml files which have been given up here, that is not the point of this answer. This is a workaround that I choose to use, feel free to use others

Comment: Inside `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged()` callback, if-condition should not be `editable.length()==0`. It should be `editable.length()>0`. Btw thanks for your solution,it helps me to work on Api-8.

Comment: If you use support-v7 for ActionBarActivity, add another line for finding `if (edit_text== null)edit_text= (EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just wanted to enable user to clear his query as it was used as keyword in API search, so the simplest idea was:

```
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userQuery = "";
        }
    });
```

where userQuery is my variable used for searching etc.

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is samvel1024's answer converted it to Kotlin.
You may need to change IME_ACTION_GO to whatever you're using for your keyboard's 'go' button. Simply run this method during your page initialization.

```
/**
 * Business: User should be allowed to perform an empty search.
 * SearchView does not cause OnQueryTextChange to fire when the box is empty.
 * To create a listener method for this scenario, we use reflection to gain access to the SearchView's inner TextView.
 */
private fun enableEmptySearch(searchView: SearchView) {
    try {
        val searchViewClass = searchView::class.java
        val currentListenerField: Field = searchViewClass.getDeclaredField("mOnEditorActionListener")
        currentListenerField.isAccessible = true
        val previousListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener = currentListenerField.get(searchView) as TextView.OnEditorActionListener
        val newListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener = TextView.OnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO && v.text.isEmpty()) {
                querySubmit()
            }
            previousListener.onEditorAction(v, actionId, event)
        }
        val innerTextViewField: Field = searchViewClass.getDeclaredField("mSearchSrcTextView")
        innerTextViewField.isAccessible = true
        (innerTextViewField.get(searchView) as TextView).setOnEditorActionListener(newListener) // Allow user to tap the "GO" button when the SearchView is empty.
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        // If a major change occurs to android SDK, internal fields mSearchSrcTextView or mOnEditorActionListener might not exist.
        // This exception will prevent this additional feature from functioning, but not crash the app or cause any other issues.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Koltin users:

Simply use the following instead of `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener`

```
val searchPlate = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.search_src_text)
        searchPlate.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                searchYourItems(searchView.query.toString()) // your code goes here
            }
            false
        }
```