# Android SearchView - empty query doesn't work

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to add recent searches to the SearchView on a toolbar:

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        if (s!= null )
        {
            if (s.isEmpty()){
                loadRecentList();
            }
            else{
                search(s);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

The search is working fine, but I can't see the recent list results.

I found this [Android SearchView.OnQueryTextListener OnQueryTextSubmit not fired on empty query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576283/android-searchview-onquerytextlistener-onquerytextsubmit-not-fired-on-empty-quer)

but modifying the ActionBar library is not a nice solution.

Does anyone have another solution? 
Thanks.

Edit:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.btn_earch);
    initSearchView();
    setSearchViewListener();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



 protected void initSearchView() {
    final String CURSOR_RESOURCE_ID = "mCursorDrawableRes";
    final int THRESHOLD = 1;

    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    mSearchView.setMeasureWithLargestChildEnabled(true);

    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(THRESHOLD);


}

protected void setSearchViewListener() {



    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (s!= null )
            {
                if (s.isEmpty()){
                    loadRecentList();
                }
                else{
                    search(s);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

btn_search item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_small"
    android:title="@string/tooltip_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Comment: Hello, can you show your onCreateOptionsMenu method please?

Answer (score 6):

I solve it with something like this

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.i("MyApp", searchView.getQuery().toString());
            consultarListaParadas(searchView.getQuery().toString());
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adaptadorListaParadasBus.setListaParadas(listaParadas);
                    adaptadorListaParadasBus.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if(newText.equals("")){
                this.onQueryTextSubmit("");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The only problem is that it throws without you press the search button.

Answer (score 0):

@Gali,

Please take a look at my code:

1) I created ActionBar Activity like that:

```
public class CarsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener
{
 //my class fields:
 private  MenuItem _menu_item;
 private SearchView _searchView;

// .......

//here is my OnCreateOptionMenu method:
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cars_activity, menu);
    _menu_item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    _searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(_menu_item);
    _searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) 
        {
           //action when search is displayed on actinbar
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) 
        {
            //action when search is collaped on actinbar
        }
    });

    _searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()  {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) 
        {

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
        {
         //listener for entering text in searchView
         //you can implement it your way
         return false;
        }
   });
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It doesn't work. While the query is empty, I still can't see the suggestion list (my recent list).

Comment: Try to add if (s.length() < 0) and load the list in it please.

Answer (score 0):

The queryTextListener wont fire on an empty string event. A solution is to find the underlining EditText on the SearchView and attach a TextWatcher to that.

Recursive method to find a view of EditText

```
 private EditText getEditText(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                View editText = getEditText(context, child);

                if (editText instanceof EditText) {
                    return (EditText) editText;
                }
            }
        } else if (v instanceof EditText) {
            Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "found edit text");
            return (EditText) v;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

then when you have your SearchView

```
EditText et = getEditText(getActivity(), searchView);

    if (et != null) {

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "empty");
                    //do stuff
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "not empty");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by create custom SearchView widget like this :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;

public class EmptySubmitSearchView extends SearchView {
    SearchView.SearchAutoComplete mSearchSrcTextView;
    OnQueryTextListener listener;

    public EmptySubmitSearchView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EmptySubmitSearchView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EmptySubmitSearchView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnQueryTextListener(OnQueryTextListener listener) {
        super.setOnQueryTextListener(listener);

        this.listener = listener;
        mSearchSrcTextView = this.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        mSearchSrcTextView.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, i, keyEvent) -> {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onQueryTextSubmit(getQuery().toString());
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

reference from this [link](https://medium.com/@_foso_/how-to-use-a-searchview-with-an-empty-query-text-submit-1ecdff651181), i just migrated it to support AndroidX