# search resultlist not getting set to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, adapter, searchview

> i m implementing search functionality with realmData i got printed searched string but the searched string not getting set to recyclerview.
>
> realm   serchfilter return complete result and print it but return mFilteredList not getting set to recyclerview

```
package "";
public class FollowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowAdapter.Holder> implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    ActionListener actionListener;
    InviteListener inviteListener;
    private String TAG = getClass().getName();

    List<ContactClass> realmList;
    private List<ContactClass> mFilteredList;


    public FollowAdapter(Context context, List<ContactClass> realmList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.realmList = realmList;
        mFilteredList = realmList;

    }

    public InviteListener getInviteListener() {
        return inviteListener;
    }

    public void setInviteListener(InviteListener inviteListener) {
        this.inviteListener = inviteListener;
    }

    public ActionListener getActionListener() {
        return actionListener;
    }

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
    }


    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.follow_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {
        final ContactClass contactClass = realmList.get(position);
        holder.contactName.setText(contactClass.getName());
         Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.camera, null);
         Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(contactClass.getAvatar()).into(holder.contact_pic).onLoadFailed(drawable);
          holder.contactNumber.setText(contactClass.getNumber());
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return realmList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    mFilteredList = realmList;
                } else {
                    List<ContactClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                    RealmQuery<ContactClass> query = realm.where(ContactClass.class).contains("name", charString, Case.INSENSITIVE);
                    RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = query.findAll();

                    for (ContactClass c : realmResults) {
                        filteredList.add(c);
                        Log.e("filter", c.getName() + "  " + c.getNumber() + "  " + c.getId());
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                if (mFilteredList != null) {
                    Log.e("sized", mFilteredList.size() + "");
                }
                mFilteredList = (List<ContactClass>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView contact_pic;
        TextView contactName, contactNumber;
        AppCompatButton follow;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            contact_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_pic);
            contactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            contactNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
            follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
            contactName.setSelected(true);
            contactNumber.setSelected(true);
        }
    }}
```

**code to search query**

```
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    followAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter the data in realm adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601880/how-to-filter-the-data-in-realm-adapter)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for link fixed it