# Expected live search in RealmRecyclerViewAdapter does not work

Tags: android, realm, searchview, realmrecyclerviewadapter

In this solution ([How to filter the data in realm adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601880/how-to-filter-the-data-in-realm-adapter)) query handles only when i press enter. Proviso: i use RealmRecyclerViewAdapter instead of RealmBaseAdapter.

How to implement live search?

Comment: Do the same thing as in that example except use a `TextWatcher` for the edit text. Or at least that's what I typically did, except I used ButterKnife and `@OnTextChanged(R.id.edit_text)`. Calling `updateData()` with the new query is what you need

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Did I understand correctly that `onQueryTextChange` doesn't provide possibility to live search so i need to make text in `SearchView` as `EditText`, and then apply `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())`?
In this case i didn't savvied what to do in overridden methods of TextWatcher.
Can you explain it in more simple terms?
I'm new to android development and for now i try not to use any libraries such a butterknife just to get used to original java logic.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if SearchView is "unable to provide it", but it didn't work that well for me, so yeah, I tend to use EditText+TextWatcher.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I was completely inconsiderated. In that example i've just change body of `onQueryTextChange` to `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`;
Works for now. `TextWatcher` wasn't needed, but I learned for myself a new.
Thanks for response!