# Filtering in RealmRecyclerViewAdapter does not hide excluded elements

Tags: java, android, filter, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm currently building an app which use a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` for displaying the elements inside `Realm`.

I was looking into implementing the `Filterable` interface, which I managed to do (thanks to those answers: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630322/how-to-implement-filterable-in-realmrecyclerviewadapter) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601880/how-to-filter-the-data-in-realm-adapter)) but now I have a side effect: when I'm filtering, the `Adapter` shows all the elements, even if they doesn't match with the filter. Also, the excluded element does show incorrect information. When I close the `SearchView`, everything is back to normal.

Here is the `Activity` when I call the `Adapter`:

```java
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm realm;
    HabitCardAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setUIMode();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set the title inside the top bar for this activity.
        // I'm not doing it inside the Manifest because it changes the app's name
        setTitle(R.string.MainActivityTitle);

        // Bottom App Bar setup
        BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
        cutBottomAppEdge(bottomAppBar);     // Diamond shape

        // Add listener to Stats button inside the bottom app bar
        MenuItem statsMenuItem = bottomAppBar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.statsMenuItem);
        statsMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.statsMenuItem){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StatsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        // FAB button setup
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fabAddButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateHabitActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.habitCardRecyclerView);
        TextView emptyMessage = findViewById(R.id.mainEmptyHabitListMessage);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Habit> results = realm.where(Habit.class).sort("id").findAll();

        results.addChangeListener(habits -> {
            if (habits.size() > 0) {
                rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                emptyMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                emptyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        //this is necessarily because it is not changed yet
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            emptyMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            emptyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new HabitCardAdapter(results, true, this, realm);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar_menu, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuItem).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.searchMenuItem:
                return true;

            case R.id.settingMenuItem:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); //FIXME: animazione
                return true;

            case R.id.aboutMenuItem:
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.about_us_title));
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.about_us_message));
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sprout_fg_small);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Set the Night/Light UI. On the first run of the app, the user get the Light UI.
     */
    private void setUIMode() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);

        int pref = preferences.getInt(SettingsActivity.SHARED_PREFS_DARK_MODE, AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(pref);
    }

    private void cutBottomAppEdge(BottomAppBar bar) {
        BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment topEdge = new SproutBottomAppBarCutCornersTopEdge(
                bar.getFabCradleMargin(),
                bar.getFabCradleRoundedCornerRadius(),
                bar.getCradleVerticalOffset());
        MaterialShapeDrawable babBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bar.getBackground();
        //It requires 1.1.0-alpha10
        babBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
                babBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
                        .toBuilder()
                        .setTopEdge(topEdge)
                        .build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the `HabitCardAdapter` which extends `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`:

```java
public class HabitCardAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Habit, HabitCardAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    Context ct;
    OrderedRealmCollection<Habit> list;
    Realm mRealm;

    public HabitCardAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Habit> data, boolean autoUpdate, Context context, Realm realm) {
        super(data, autoUpdate); //autoUpdate to true
        ct = context;
        list = data;
        mRealm = realm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HabitCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        //TODO: inflatare diversi tipi di carte a seconda del habitType
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_habit_counter_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HabitCardAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Habit habit = getItem(position);
        if (habit != null) {
            holder.setHabit(habit);

            holder.editHabitButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ct, EditHabitActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("HABIT_ID", habit.getId());
                //TODO: Aggiungere l'animazione
                ct.startActivity(intent);
            });

            holder.checkButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                int habitId = habit.getId();
                int newRepValue = habit.getRepetitions() + 1;
                int maxReps = habit.getMaxRepetitions();
                Log.d("Testing", newRepValue + " - " + maxReps);
                if (newRepValue <= habit.getMaxRepetitions()) {
                    habit.getRealm().executeTransaction(realm -> {
                        Habit result = realm.where(Habit.class).equalTo("id", habitId).findFirst();
                        if (result != null) {
                            result.setRepetitions(newRepValue);
                            String newLabel = "Completato " + newRepValue + " volte su " + maxReps;
                            holder.progressLabel.setText(newLabel);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public void filterResults(String text) {
        text = text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();

        if (text == null || "".equals(text)) {
            updateData(mRealm.where(Habit.class).sort("id").findAllAsync());
        } else {
            updateData(mRealm.where(Habit.class).contains("title", text).sort("id").findAllAsync());
        }

    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        HabitFilter filter = new HabitFilter(this);
        return filter;
    }

    private class HabitFilter extends Filter {
        private final HabitCardAdapter adapter;

        private HabitFilter(HabitCardAdapter adapter) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return new FilterResults();
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            adapter.filterResults(charSequence.toString());
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView habitTitle;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView progressLabel;
        ImageButton editHabitButton;
        Button checkButton;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            habitTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.habitCardTitle);
            editHabitButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counterHabitEditButton);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counterHabitProgressBar);
            checkButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkButton);
            progressLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counterHabitProgressLabel);
        }

        void setHabit(Habit habit) {
            this.habitTitle.setText(habit.getTitle());
            this.progressBar.setProgress(habit.getRepetitions());
            this.progressBar.setMax(habit.getMaxRepetitions());
            this.progressLabel.setText("Completato " + habit.getRepetitions() + " volte su " + habit.getMaxRepetitions()); //FIXME: sposta la stringa
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if this is the way to go for this problem, but it's now behaving as expected so I'll share the solution here.

Inside the `HabitCardAdapter` I added another `OrderedRealmCollection<Habit>` member, called `filteredList`, while `list` holds the whole data. In the costructor both of `filteredList` and `list` are tied to the data passed to the constructor, but while `filteredList` will be modified by the query, `list` will not (probably putting it to `final` is the best practice). Then everything in the `Adapter` will now reference to `filteredList` instead of `list`, and when the `SearchView` is selected and the query is up, `filteredList` will get the data, and then `updateData(filteredList)` will be called.

Here is what I changed:

```java
public class HabitCardAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Habit, HabitCardAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    Context ct;
    OrderedRealmCollection<Habit> list;
    OrderedRealmCollection<Habit> filteredList;
    Realm mRealm;

    ...
}
```

```java
public HabitCardAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Habit> data, Context context, Realm realm) {
        super(data, true, true);
        ct = context;
        list = data;
        filteredList = data;
        mRealm = realm;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }
```

Probably the error was here in `getItemCount()`, when the `filteredList`size was smaller than the `list` one, but since I didn't have any reference to `filteredList`, I didn't have any way to change that size, and so the `Adapter` would continue to show - for example - 6 views while I was querying for 3. Having it as a properly class member it let me make this:

```java
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.filteredList.size();
    }
```

```java
public void filterResults(String text) {
        text = text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();
        if (text == null || "".equals(text)) {
            filteredList = list;
        } else {
            filteredList = mRealm.where(Habit.class).beginsWith("title", text, Case.INSENSITIVE).sort("id").findAll();
        }
        updateData(filteredList);
    }
```